# mysqldatabase is not reflecting post request in Postman

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I want to connect myback-end folder with mysql database on localhost using npm package knex with mysql.

Steps:

1. Run nodemon server.js file in the backend project folder (that has knex and mysql)
2. In Postman, I do:

Open Postman, select Post Requst, copy URL: localhost:3000/mypath, copy into body:

{
"email":"me@gmail.com",
"password":"Bananas",
"name":"Test"
}

3. Click Send
4. When I open database, run the query: "SELECT * FROM users;" - I don't see any data there.

Do you know what might be going?

here is the code in server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const db = require('knex') ({
client: 'mysql',
connection: {
 host: '127.0.0.1',
 user: 'root',
 password: 'root',
 database: 'mydatabase'
}
```

});

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const database = {
 users: [
  {
    id: '123',
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@gmail.com',
    password: 'cookies'
    },
  {
   id: '124',
   name: 'Sally',
   email: 'sally@gmail.com',
   password: 'cake', 
   }
  ]
}

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
res.send(database.users);
```

})

```
app.post('/mypath', (req,res) => {
const {email, name, password} = req.body;
db('users').insert({
name: name,
email: email,
password: password
}).then (console.log(req.body))
   res.json(database.users);
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('app is running on port 3000');
})
```

For some reason, I get the error: "node:13376 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated."

Comment: Can you show the `req.body` from you request? Can you full content of your express app file?

Comment: The request body is in Postman: { "email":"me@gmail.com", "password":"Bananas", "name":"Test" } - I don't have request body in express app file. I want to post json data to database using Postman. For some reason, no data is posted to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the bodyparser middleware from express.
In order to do that, just make the following configuration:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json()); //<-- this is the configuration you need.
//Your db configuration

app.post('/mypath', (req,res) => {
   console.log(req.body) //now your body is defined.
})
```

Activating the `express.json()` will parse your requests if they come with 'content-type': `application/json` headers.

You are having the rejectionErrorHandler, because you have to catch errors after your `.then()` function. Here is an example:

```
exports.createUser = (req, res) => {
    db.get().collection('user').insertOne({ "name": req.body.name, "login": req.body.login, "password": req.body.password }).then((result) => {
        res.set('location', `/users/${result.insertedId}`)
        res.status(201).end()
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({ errors: err.message })
    })
}
```

Comment: Hello! I added full code in server.js file. Things are not working. Plus, I get UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning. Please let me know what's going in. Thank You

Comment: do you received the body content ?

Comment: Just edited my answer with the information about UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Comment: yes, I did receive body content in Postman as request returned with status 200. But, when I run, in MySQL: "SELECT * FROM users;"  - I get no records. The example that you provide is too advanced. I am newbie taking Udemy Web Dev Course. Could you please provide some basic concepts I need to understand to resolve this issue - just give key words. Thank You!

Comment: I found the problem. It has to do with removing privileges in MySQL.